# Delete query not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an stored procedure in sql server that in first step inserts some data from one table to another and then delete data that inserted in second table from first table; Maybe it's a complicated description, so let see the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Insert_NotificationUserBulk]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[NotificationUserBulk]
       ([NotificationId]
       ,[UserId]
       ,[IsNotify]
       ,[IsShow]
       ,[NotifyMethod]
       ,[NotifyDateTime]
       ,[ShowDateTime]
       ,[IsDeleted]
       ,[CreatedDate]
       ,[ModifiedDate])
 
 (SELECT 
UserId,
NotificationId,
IsNotify,
IsShow,
NotifyMethod,
NotifyDateTime,
ShowDateTime,
IsDeleted,
CreatedDate,ModifiedDate
FROM NotificationUsers WHERE IsShow=1 OR IsDeleted=1)

DELETE FROM dbo.NotificationUsers WHERE IsShow=1 OR IsDeleted=1
   RETURN
END
```

Insert statement execute successfully and there is no problem but in Delete statement not working and nothing happens.
So what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's my fault and I fix it. Thank you but it's not related to that and it execute outside of stored procedure successfully

Comment: Not considering why your delete doesn't work - these should be transactionally consistent and should be within a `begin/end transaction`. You can also do this in a single statement using `output`. also, be consistent in your schema prefix - either use `dbo` consistently or don't, otherwise you risk ambiguity.

Comment: There's also the [single statement option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql#j-using-output-with-from_table_name-in-a-delete-statement), since SQL Server supports `delete TableA output ... into TableB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-time or ad hoc query you could try something like this.   If it's oltp then you could add `TRY/CATCH` and return a success/failure variable.

In an explicit transaction with `XACT_ABORT ON` the query inserts into 'NotificationUsers' table, outputs (the inserted) NotificationId's into a temp table, and deletes from 'NotificationUsers' based on an `INNER JOIN` with the temp table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Insert_NotificationUserBulk]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET xact_abort on;

begin transaction 
    declare @NotificationId             table(NotificationId        int primary key);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[NotificationUserBulk]
           ([NotificationId]
           ,[UserId]
           ,[IsNotify]
           ,[IsShow]
           ,[NotifyMethod]
           ,[NotifyDateTime]
           ,[ShowDateTime]
           ,[IsDeleted]
           ,[CreatedDate]
           ,[ModifiedDate])
    output inserted.NotificationId into @NotificationId 
    SELECT UserId, NotificationId, IsNotify, IsShow, NotifyMethod,
           NotifyDateTime, ShowDateTime, IsDeleted, CreatedDate, 
           ModifiedDate
    FROM NotificationUsers
    WHERE IsShow=1 
          OR IsDeleted=1;

    DELETE nu
    from dbo.NotificationUsers nu
         join @NotificationId n on nu.NotificationId=n.NotificationId;
commit
go
```

Comment: I did something like this and now sp execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

please do not use RETURN after DELETE Query, try to simple Query

```
DELETE FROM dbo.NotificationUsers WHERE IsShow=1 OR IsDeleted=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but it's not the solution